# Inject multiple javascript sources in nw.js

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

I'm trying to inject multiple scripts when the Window opens:

```
gui.Window.open (goToURL, {
  focus: true,
  position: 'center',
  width: 1280,
  height: 1024,
  'inject-js-end': ['./js/script1.js', './js/script2.js']
});
```

So far no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for this is to combine both of your JS files into a single file using a tool like browserify.

Comment: Thanks, this will do!